# how to print primefaces schedule in pdf?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a primefaces schedule that i want to print when the user click on a button i searched but didnt found how to print it .
i found also is like jQuery fullCalendar but i didnt understand how i can print the schedule.

thats my shedule code :

```
  <p:schedule  id="schedule" value="#{ cuissonManagedBean.eventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule" locale="fr" timeFormat="H:m" axisFormat="H:m" view="agendaWeek" draggable="false" resizable="false" > 
    </p:schedule>
```

how can i print the schedule ??

**Edit :** i tryed this solution

```
 <p:commandButton id="toPrint" value="Print" ajax="false">
        <p:printer target="schedule" />
    </p:commandButton>      
   <p:schedule  id="schedule" value="#{ cuissonManagedBean.eventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule" locale="fr" timeFormat="H:m" axisFormat="H:m" view="agendaWeek" draggable="false" resizable="false" > 
    </p:schedule>
```

but i didnt get the full calendar and with out colors thats what i get :
[image]

how i can get good result with full calendar and good colors ??

Comment: The schedule is not made by primefaces. PF only works as a middleman for a jQuery plugin, fullcalendar. So getting programatically a visual output on PDF of the schedule will be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the primefaces printer functionality: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/printer.jsf

Check out the documentation for more info:
http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/indexed_primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf

Here is an example:

```
<h:form id="mainForm" style="overflow:hidden;">

    <primefaces:commandButton id="toPrint" value="Print" ajax="false">
        <primefaces:printer target="schedule" />
    </primefaces:commandButton>
    <primefaces:schedule id="schedule" value="#{myBackingBean.eventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule">  

    </primefaces:schedule>

</h:form>
```

Backing bean

```
ScheduleModel eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();

public ScheduleModel getEventModel(){
return eventModel;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? I can print a schedule (see my edited answer for an example) - what have you actually tried?

Comment: see my update i got a result as xps file but the display is very weak

Comment: I am facing same problem, hey Masouanoviche have You got any solution for this?.urgently required

Answer (score 0):

Here is another thing you can do: in Chrome, you must enable "more options", and there is an option to print with background colors.

[image: screen shot of an option dialog]

Comment: Hi Felipe -- great answer. I think it might be improved if you include a screenshot of where the button is, if you have time to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Erty, i put a example on firefox because i dont have a print in my manjaro, but this is the page